# formData and "select multiple"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to submit a dynamically generated form which includes a file upload. 
For this purpose, I'm getting the form fields via a DB-connection. It is possible for a field to allow multiple selected options. The form can look something like this:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="xyz"> </input>
<input type="file" name="xyzfile"> </input>
<select multiple name="...">
<option value="...">1</option>
<option value="...">2</option>
...
<option>x</option>
</select>
<select name="...">
<option value="...">1</option>
<option value="...">2</option>
</select>
```

Unfortunately, when I use a formData-Object to submit the form, only the last selected option for a given field gets transmitted. The "multiple" attribute is somehow ignored.

This is my code:

```
var pId = '1';
metaForm = $('#metaForm')[0];
formData = new FormData(metaForm);
formData.append('a','saveInstance');
          formData.append('pId', pId);
$.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'x.php',
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false,
                  data: formData,

                  success: function (response) {
...
```

When I examine the metaForm-Object, all entries that were selected have the attribute selected = true.
Is there an option I'm not seeing to get ALL the selected entries for one select-field, when using the formData-constructor?
Do I have to do this manually using formData.append()? If so, how do I make sure I do not get any duplicates when using the constructor AND append()?

This is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Here just name your `<select>` with `[]` at the end, and get it as an array in your php script.

Comment: You're right! I didn't think of that. Your comment was actually the answer, thanks!

Comment: @Kaiido, even though the answer is basically the same as the other question, I disagree that this question is an exact duplicate. The other question is about checkboxes, and this is about multiple select; and since I was wondering how to solve this for a multiple select, your one sentence answer in the context of this question was far more helpful to me than the accepted answer on the other.

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize your form data before posting like below code:

```
var formPostData  = $("#formID").serialize();
```

Comment: i would be very glad if u answer this question. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51758955/inserting-data-of-multiple-fields-into-database-table-using-formdata-class-of-js)[Link].