# Inserting data of multiple fields into database table using FormData Class of JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I need to insert data into MySql database table Using ajax and FormData Class.  I can easily  solve my this issue with declaring many variables for many `<input>` using jquery And then put these variables  for checks in if-else syntax. But what I need is to use `FormData` class of JavaScript and I distribute my code in 3 files:

**action_project.php**

```
<?php
  require_once("../config.php");
  include(CLASSES_PATH.DS.'project.php');

$objProject = new Project();

if(isset($_POST)) {

$product            = isset($_POST['product'])?$_POST['product']:'';
$customer           = isset($_POST['cutomer'])?$_POST['cutomer']:'';
echo $objProject->AddProject($customer,$product);
?>
```

**project.php**

```
 class Project
 {
private $mysqli_lib;

function __construct()
{
    global $obj_mysql;
    $this->mysqli_lib = $obj_mysql;
}


function AddProject($customer,$product)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_project_detail(customer,product) VALUES ('$customer','$product')";
     $response = $this->mysqli_lib->insert($query);
    return $response > 0 ? "success" : "fail";
}
}
```

**project_view.php** (for the sake of clarity i get rid of some html element tags)

```
  <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="fieldsform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" style="clear:both">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product" value="product" 
   id="product">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer" value="customer" 
   id="product">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnQuoSave" id 
    ="btnQuoSave">Save</button>
  </form>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '#btnQuoSave', function () {

        var formdata = new FormData($('#fieldsform')); //I need to figure out this line of code to work, i think.

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../includes/ajax/action_project.php",
            async: true,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            data: formdata,

            success: function(data){
            data = data.trim();
            //console.log(data);
            //alert(data);

            if(data == 'success'){
             alert('sucess');

            }else if(data == 'fail'){
                alert('fail');
              }

           }

    });

     });  
  });
```

**So My Questing is How should i insert data into MySql database table Using ajax and FormData Class?**

Comment: where is `#fieldsform` in html form?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add? wait.

Comment: Your form input names do not match with your indexes of `$_POST` array in php

Comment: OH god what is worng with me.changed the input name.

Comment: `$('#fieldsform')` is returning a jQuery object, whereas you need a native HTMLElement to pass to the constructor for the FormData object. Consider finding out how to extract a native DOM element from a jQuery one. ;)

Comment: why this class does not do automatically? I retrieve the whole `<form>` with `id=fieldsform` `<input>`.

Comment: Are you asking why a built-in class implemented by the browser doesn't extract a native object from a third-party framework? Of course, the other way to go about it would be just to select the form element natively. You'd do that with the simple: `document.getElementById('fieldsform')`

Comment: your saying that i should write this:`document.getElementById('fieldsform').val;` and passed this value in FormData().?

Comment: what about jquery?